# Tabla escondida en el código no se puede scrapear

Tags: html, python, selenium

Buenas a todos

Estoy intentando obtener información de una web con selenium y BSoup. La página es la siguiente

http://www.nowgoal.com

A grandes rasgos, es una tabla con los partidos de fútbol que se juegan en ese día. si bajais hasta abajo aparecerán los partidos ya disputados ese día, aunque para ver a qué me refiero vale casi cualquier partido.
Si pones el cursor sobre los corners, que son los números en letra negra a la derecha del nombre de los equipos y justo encima de otros números con letra roja, os aparecerá una tabla con el siguiente título "Bet365 Corner Kicks".

Bien, esa tabla no aparece en el código de la página cuando hago "inspeccionar elemento", y como no tengo referencias de cómo está integrada en el arbol de la página, no soy capaz de sacar información de ella. Aunque al ser visible, debería estar por algún lado.

No se si es porque en este caso es una tabla que aparece solo al poner el cursor encima (no se puede clicar), pero no se como afrontar el scrapeo de dichos datos.

Si alguien me pone un ejemplo, o me direcciona a cómo hacerlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para aclararnos supongo que te refieres a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que la tabla que quieres es generada de forma dinámica usando javascript. Cuando se posiciona el puntero encima se llama a la función js `showSBCorner()` y cuando se quita el puntero de encima se llama a `hiddenSbCorner()`.

Dado que usas Selenium la opción más simple es imitar la acción de posicionar el puntero encima y en ese momento seleccionar la tabla. Para ello usa [Action Chains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) y el método `move_to_element()`.

Dejo el código (Usando Geckodriver) con comentarios de cada paso:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.nowgoal.com")
timeout = 30

# Seleccionamos la tabla cuando esté cargada
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "table_live"))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
table = driver.find_element_by_id("table_live")

# Obtenemos todas las filas de la tabla que queremos
rows = table.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr[contains(@id, "tr1_")]')

# A modo de ejemplo vamos a usar solo la primera fila
# Seleccionamos el elemento de la primera fila que ql posicionar el ratón abre la tabla
first_row = rows[0].find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "cr_")]')

# Colocamos el puntero del ratón encima
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(first_row).perform()

# Ahora seleccionamos la tabla "oculta"
corner_table = driver.find_element_by_id("sbOddsCorner")

# Ahora hacemos con ella lo que queramos, por ejemplo obtener el html
html = corner_table.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(html)

driver.close()
```

**Salida obtenida**(html de la tabla de Bet365 Corner Kicks del primer partido):

```html
<table id="tab_CornerOdds" style="background-color:#cccccc;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td colspan="2"><div class="jqTitle">Bet365 Corner Kicks</div></td></tr><tr class="jqSubTitle"><td>USM Bel Abbes</td><td>Paradou AC</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="info" id="div_cornerOdds" style="display:" odds="1427321,11388,3182,3,,,,1.00,7.5,0.80,2,5,1,2,11388,83"><div class="jqSubTitle2"><span>Handicap</span><span style="width:199px; border-left:solid 1px #cccccc;">Over/Under</span></div><table id="tab_CornerOdds" style="background-color:#cccccc;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="58"></td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="58"></td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="58"></td><td bgcolor="#EFF5EE" width="58">First Odds</td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="58">0.90</td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="58">8.5</td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="58">0.90</td></tr> <tr><td bgcolor="#FEF7ED"></td><td bgcolor="#FEF7ED"></td><td bgcolor="#FEF7ED"></td><td bgcolor="#EFF5EE">Live Odds</td><td bgcolor="#FEF7ED"><div class="up_red">1.00</div></td><td bgcolor="#FEF7ED">7.5</td><td bgcolor="#FEF7ED"><div class="down_green">0.80</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="info" id="div_cornerDetail" style="display:"><div class="jqTitle2">Corner Detail</div><table id="tab_CornerDetail" style="margin-top:-1px;background-color:#cccccc;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="169">2</td><td bgcolor="#EFF5EE" width="56">Full Time</td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">5</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">1</td><td bgcolor="#EFF5EE">Half Time</td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">2</td></tr><tr><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="/images/rq.jpg" width="16" height="18"></td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#EFF5EE">10'</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#EFF5EE">13'</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="/images/bq.jpg" width="16" height="18"></td></tr><tr><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#EFF5EE">25'</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="/images/bq.jpg" width="16" height="18"></td></tr><tr><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#EFF5EE">48'</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="/images/bq.jpg" width="16" height="18"></td></tr><tr><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#EFF5EE">55'</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="/images/bq.jpg" width="16" height="18"></td></tr><tr><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#EFF5EE">71'</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="/images/bq.jpg" width="16" height="18"></td></tr><tr><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="/images/rq.jpg" width="16" height="18"></td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#EFF5EE">83'</td><td style="line-height: 18px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

El código está hecho de forma rápida, es posible que se pueda pulir o que algo se me escapara. No obstante esta es la idea.